# Install openshift 4.5 on existing VPC in AWS

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise, okd

Very new to openshift and I am trying to install openshift 4.5 in our AWS environment in exiting VPC without creating new VPC. I have tried quick installation without custom "install-config.yaml" but it creates new VPC, new Route53, new subnets, new routes etc but that is not my goal. I followed this link https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-vpc.html provided by Redhat changed "install-config.yaml" to input all necessary information but still no luck. The errors I am getting varies for example i get "FATAL failed to fetch Metadata: failed to load asset "Install Config": invalid "install-config.yaml" file: [platform: Invalid value:"

In addition to that we are also trying to encrypt EBS volume with KMS according to this page https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/release_notes/ocp-4-5-release-notes.html#ocp-4-5-encrypt-ebs-instance-volumes-with-kms-key

My question is it possible to install openshift version 4.5 on existing AWS VPC inside existing subnet? If so where do I put the values to point to existing VPC and existing subnet.

Second question is the base install image has to be redhat core os for OCP 4.5  and fedora core os for OKD 4.5 can it be centos ?

I am using following "install-config.yaml" file to run the install and please note some values are changed.

```
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: okdv4.example.com
controlPlane:
  hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: master
  platform:
    aws:
      zones:
      - eu-west-2a
      - eu-west-2b
      rootVolume:
        iops: 4000
        size: 500
        type: io1
        kmsKeyARN: arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:11111111:key/f2222222222
      type: t3a.large
  replicas: 3
compute:
- hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: worker
  platform:
    aws:
      rootVolume:
        iops: 2000
        size: 500
        type: io1
        kmsKeyARN: arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:11111111:key/f2222222222
      type: t3a.xlarge
      zones:
      - eu-west-2c
  replicas: 3
metadata:
  name: okd4.cluster
networking:
  clusterNetwork:
  - cidr: 30.128.0.0/14
    hostPrefix: 23
  machineNetwork:
  - cidr: 30.169.4.0/26
  - cidr: 30.169.4.192/26
  - cidr: 30.169.4.64/26
  networkType: OpenShiftSDN
  serviceNetwork:
  - 30.169.4.128/26
platform:
  aws:
    region: eu-west-2
    userTags:
      adminContact: John Doe
      costCenter: 700.070
    subnets:
    - subnet-0ae1111111111
    - subnet-0e72222222222
    - subnet-0d33333333333
    - subnet-0b44444444444
    amiID: ami-004b8123456789
    serviceEndpoints:
    - name: ec2
       url: https://ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
pullSecret: '{"auths":{"cloud.openshift.com":{"auth":"Nk5NR0tGMUdBTUZHWVJRQkw}}}'
fips: false
sshKey: |
  ssh-rsa 3miJ9QzqQi8jVD
publish: Internal
```

Comment: The error indicates that your install-config not properly formatted. From what I see above your install-config has typos (for example "platforim"). You should fix these and retry, then read the error message.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for pointing out and I have not corrected the "install-config.yaml" file. Now I am receiving error related to permission "FATAL failed to fetch Cluster: failed to generate asset "Cluster": AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::1111111111:user/openshift is not authorized to perform: tag:TagResources
        status code: 400, request id: 1257f560-a701-4cf5-a2b8-92cf064e1a6a"

Comment: It seems that your user ("openshift") that you are using for AWS is not allowed to tag resources. So you need to check AWS IAM if your user has the required permissions. You can find a complete list of the required permissions in the documentation: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-account.html#installation-aws-permissions_installing-aws-account

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks I am looking into IAM permission however my initial questions are:                                     My question is it possible to install openshift version 4.5 on existing AWS VPC inside existing subnet? If so where do I put the values to point to existing VPC and existing subnet.

Second question is the base install image has to be redhat core os for OCP 4.5 and fedora core os for OKD 4.5 can it be centos ?

Comment: Yes, as outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_aws/installing-aws-vpc.html). You put your subnets in `platform.aws.subnets` and then these will be used (VPC ID will be read from those). There is a good sample in the documentation. As far as I know, there is no CentOS option, only CoreOS (OCP) and Fedora CoreOS (OKD).

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks I am able to install openshift cluster in existing VPC but there are still couple of issues I need to sort out. 1) How can I configure install-config.yaml to use existing security groups not create a new one? Is this possible? 2) How can I use my existing AWS keypairs rather it with new one so I can ssh to instances using existing keypair? 3) Is FCOS is only supported can I use community ami to build base image? Apologies for too many questions.

Comment: Hi Simon, I know OKD 4 supports Fedora Core OS but would it support Fedora 33 as on this link https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B08LZY538M?ref=cns_srchrow#pdp-usage